# Creating a union on the left side of an Either type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz, category-theory

Is there a way to bind a value of `Either[L1, R1]` to a function of type `R1 => Either[L2, R2]` and get a value of `Either[L1 | L2, R2]` so individual functions can declare and potentially return their errors and consumers of a monadic pipeline of these functions can cleanly handle all possible errors in an exhaustive, type-safe way?

**Edit**

Here's an example...

```
sealed trait IncrementError
case object MaximumValueReached extends IncrementError

def increment(n: Int): Either[IncrementError, Int] = n match {
  case Integer.MAX_VALUE => Left(MaximumValueReached)
  case n => Right(n + 1)
}

sealed trait DecrementError
case object MinimumValueReached extends DecrementError

def decrement(n: Int): Either[DecrementError, Int] = n match {
  case Integer.MIN_VALUE => Left(MinimumValueReached)
  case n => Right(n - 1)
}

for {
  n <- increment(0).right
  n <- decrement(n).right
} yield n // scala.util.Either[Object, Int] = Right(0)
```

With that return type I'm not able to do exhaustive error handling. I'm curious if there exists a way to do this using standard Scala `Either` or if there exists something in a library like [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) which supports this behavior. I'd like to be able to handle errors like this...

```
val n = for {
  n <- increment(0).right
  n <- decrement(n).right
} yield n // scala.util.Either[IncrementError | DecrementError, Int]

match n {
  case Left(MaximumValueReached) => println("Maximum value reached!")
  case Left(MinimumValueReached) => println("Minimum value reached!")
  case Right(_) => println("Success!")
}
```

Comment: standard `Either` allows you to map/flatMap only in a biased way by converting it to either `LeftProjection` or `RightProjection`. It's not that convenient as you would like in your suggestion, but in fact quite workable :)

Comment: What do you mean by `L1 | L2`? You can use right projection, but the result type will be `[LC, RC]` where e.g. `LC` is the closest common ancestor of `L1` and `L2`. Is it what you expect?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar Is there anything in Scalaz or Cats which supports this behavior?

Comment: I have not used Either from scalaz but they have one, it is right-biased and they claim it is more useful for monadic context. Look at https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala

Comment: But really there is no such stuff as `IncrementError | DecrementError`. I can see logically what you mean, but as @Victor Moroz already mentioned you can have some common ancestor trait for your both errors. Or you can declare the result type as `Either[Int, Either[IncrementError, DecrementError]]` in case if you don't want to inherit these 2 errors from some parent trait.

Comment: The problem with monadic approach is that monads do not compose. So you need to use the same monad type, which means you need a sum type for `L1` and `L2`. Sum type in Scala is implemented by extending from a common ancestor. `L1 extends L`, `L2 extends L` etc. It's possible to create a substitute of a sum type with `Either`, but it has limited use.

Answer (score 0):

I would do following:

```
/**
  * Created by alex on 10/3/16.
  */
object Temp{
  sealed trait IncrementError
  case object MaximumValueReached extends IncrementError
  sealed trait DecrementError
  case object MinimumValueReached extends DecrementError

  type MyResult = Either[Either[IncrementError, DecrementError], Int]

  def increment(n: Int): MyResult = n match {
    case Integer.MAX_VALUE => Left(Left(MaximumValueReached))
    case n => Right(n + 1)
  }

  def decrement(n: Int): MyResult = n match {
    case Integer.MIN_VALUE => Left(Right(MinimumValueReached))
    case n => Right(n - 1)
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val result = for {
      k <- increment(0).right
      n <- decrement(k).right
    } yield n

    result match {
      case Left(Left(MaximumValueReached)) => println("Maximum value reached!")
      case Left(Right(MinimumValueReached)) => println("Minimum value reached!")
      case Right(_) => println("Success!")
    }
  }
}
```

Honestly I don't like it but it works for the case if you don't want to have `IncrementError` and `DecrementError` to inherit from some ancestor trait for some reasons.